# Java libgdx get clicked square without iter

Tags: opengl, java, 2d, libgdx, algorithm

[image: square grid]

I would like to detect which square is clicked without iterating over all elements!

i don't want to do this anymore for all elements.

```
 if( x >= this.getAnchorX()-HalfWidth  && x <= this.getAnchorX()+HalfWidth  && y <= this.getAnchorY()+HalfHeight && y >= this.getAnchorY()-HalfHeight )
        return true;
    else return false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that top left is at 0, and each tile is square with length 10:

```
int squareClickedX = clickPosX / 10
int squareClickedY = clickPosY / 10
```

So, if clicked on x23, y12

```
int squareClickedX = 23 / 10
int squareClickedY = 12 / 10
```

results

```
int squareClickedX = 2
int squareClickedY = 1
```

Means that you clicked

[image]

Was this any good? This is quite common way to handle this kind of stuff.